# How to delete an element from an array[,]?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove an element of this array

```
int[,] numbers = { {1,0} , {3,4} , {9,2} , {4,0} };  
int[,] Remove = {{4,0}};
```

Comment: You cannot "remove" elements from an array, because they're fixed size.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size so, you would either have to create a new array minus the item you want to delete, or make like easy and just use a list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032394/how-to-delete-a-chosen-element-in-array refere this

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992728/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-2d-array-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove items from an `Array` because they are a fixed size I would use:

`List<Tuple<int,int>>`

this way you still have a list of two dimensional objects with the ability to remove them as well using

`List.Remove()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't - arrays are fixed size. You can set the value to null. Best is to use generic collections such as `List<int[]>` which will allow you to add, insert and remove values.