# How to convert list of arrays into a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I need to convert the following collection into double[,]:

```
 var ret = new List<double[]>();
```

All the arrays in the list have the same length. The simplest approach, `ret.ToArray()`, produces double[][], which is not what I want. Of course, I can create a new array manually, and copy numbers over in a loop, but is there a more elegant way?

**Edit:** my library is invoked from a different language, Mathematica, which has not been developed in .Net. I don't think that language can utilize jagged arrays. I do have to return a multidimensional array.

Comment: sounds like you want a *jagged* array not a 2D array - are you sure that is your requirement since all arrays have the same length?

Comment: it would probably be more elegant to change the code that needs the multidimensional array.

Comment: Perhaps you should post code that explains exactly what you want and explain why you want it that way.

Comment: What's wrong with just copying the data?  At the end of the day to change the structure that's going to need to happen, and the double for loop isn't complex enough that I see the need to spend time and effort changing it into something else.  If you do it a lot, you could make a utility method to do the conversion.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the output as a jagged array if you can.
[What is differences between Multidimensional array and Array of Arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built into the framework to do this - even `Array.Copy` fails in this case. However, it's easy to write the code to do it by looping:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>
        {
            new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new[] { 4, 5, 6 },
        };

        int[,] array = CreateRectangularArray(list);
        foreach (int x in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        }
        Console.WriteLine(array[1, 2]); // 6
    }

    static T[,] CreateRectangularArray<T>(IList<T[]> arrays)
    {
        // TODO: Validation and special-casing for arrays.Count == 0
        int minorLength = arrays[0].Length;
        T[,] ret = new T[arrays.Count, minorLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
        {
            var array = arrays[i];
            if (array.Length != minorLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException
                    ("All arrays must be the same length");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < minorLength; j++)
            {
                ret[i, j] = array[j];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! I am a big fan of your book. Although my code looks similar, yours is way more reusable.

Comment: "I don't believe there's anything built into the framework to do this" - this is the most informative part of the answer. Like. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do following as extension:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Conerts source to 2D array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// The type of item that must exist in the source.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// The source to convert.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    /// Thrown if source is null.
    /// </exception>
    /// <returns>
    /// The 2D array of source items.
    /// </returns>
    public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IList<IList<T>> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        int max = source.Select(l => l).Max(l => l.Count());

        var result = new T[source.Count, max];

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < source[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = source[i][j];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If I create an extension method for a widely used thing, that will slow down my builds, right?

Comment: No, it is just as normal method

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to copy (I can't think of a better way)

```
var width = ret[0].length;
var length = ret.Count;
var newResult = new double[width, length]
Buffer.BlockCopy(ret.SelectMany(r => r).ToArray(),
                    0, 
                    newResult, 
                    0, 
                    length * width);
return newResult;
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm almost certain looping rather than using `SelectMany` and `ToArray` is faster.

I know when I've been skeeted.

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way to do this because in the situation you're describing, there's nothing stopping the `double[]` arrays in the list from being different sizes, which would be incompatible with a two-dimensional rectangular array.  However, if you are in the position to guarantee the `double[]` arrays all have the same dimensionality, you can construct your two-dimensional array as follows:

```
var arr = new double[ret.Count(),ret[0].Count()];

for( int i=0; i<ret.Count(); i++ ) {
  for( int j=0; j<ret[i].Count(); j++ )
    arr[i,j] = ret[i][j];
}
```

This will produce a run-time error if any of the `double[]` arrays in the list are shorter than the first one, and you will lose data if any of the arrays are bigger than the first one.

If you are really determined to store a jagged array in a rectangular array, you can use a "magic" value to indicate there is no value in that position.  For example:

```
var arr = new double[ret.Count(),ret.Max(x=>x.Count())];

for( int i=0; i<ret.Count(); i++ ) {
  for( int j=0; j<arr.GetLength(1); j++ )
    arr[i,j] = j<ret[i].Count() ? ret[i][j] : Double.NaN;
}
```

On an editorial note, I think this is a Very Bad Idea™; when you go to use the rectangular array, you have to check for `Double.NaN` all the time.  Furthermore, what if you wanted to use `Double.NaN` as a legitimate value in the array?  If you have a jagged array, you should just leave it as a jagged array.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing stopping the double[] arrays in the list from being different sizes. I know that all the arrays have the same sizes, but .Net does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the reverse requirement, i needed to convert a 2-dimensions array to an array of arrays. I needed this because json doesn't natively support a serialization of multi-dimensional arrays.

```
/// <summary>
/// converts a 2 dimensional array to an array of arrays
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">type of arays</typeparam>
/// <param name="src">2-dimensional array</param>
/// <returns>array of arrays of the same size the <paramref name="src"/></returns>
public static T[][] Convert2DArray<T>(this T[,] src)
{
    // match input
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    // get array dimensions
    var height = src.GetLength(0);
    var width = src.GetLength(1);

    // create the new array
    var tgt = new T[height][];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        tgt[i] = new T[width];
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            tgt[i][j] = src[i, j];
    }

    // return it
    return tgt;
}
```

Here is a 3 dimensional version:

```
/// <summary>
/// converts a 3 dimensional array to an array of arrays
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">type of arays</typeparam>
/// <param name="src">3-dimensional array</param>
/// <returns>array of arrays of the same size the <paramref name="src"/></returns>
public static TDest[][][] Convert3DArray<TSrc, TDest>(this TSrc[,,] src, Func<TSrc, TDest> converter)
{
    // match input
    if (src == null)
        return null;
    if (converter is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));

    // get array dimensions
    var iLen = src.GetLength(0);
    var jLen = src.GetLength(1);
    var kLen = src.GetLength(2);

    // create the new array
    var tgt = new TDest[iLen][][];
    for (int i = 0; i < iLen; i++)
    {
        tgt[i] = new TDest[jLen][];
        for (int j = 0; j < jLen; j++)
        {
            tgt[i][j] = new TDest[kLen];
            for (int k = 0; k < kLen; k++)
                tgt[i][j][k] = converter(src[i, j, k]);
        }
    }
    // return it
    return tgt;
}
```

And for extra fun, this function can be used to remove a dimension at the same time (3D->2D)

```
/// <summary>
/// converts a 3 dimensional array to an array of arrays (2D)
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">type of arays</typeparam>
/// <param name="src">3-dimensional array</param>
/// <param name="converter">a function to convert the 3rd dimension into a new type (e.g. concatenated string)</param>
/// <returns>array of arrays of the same size the <paramref name="src"/></returns>
public static TDest[][] Convert3DTo2DArray<TSrc, TDest>(this TSrc[,,] src, Func<IEnumerable<TSrc>, TDest> converter)
{
    // match input
    if (src == null)
        return null;
    if (converter is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));

    // get array dimensions
    var iLen = src.GetLength(0);
    var jLen = src.GetLength(1);
    var kLen = src.GetLength(2);

    // create the new array
    var tgt = new TDest[iLen][];
    for (int i = 0; i < iLen; i++)
    {
        tgt[i] = new TDest[jLen];
        for (int j = 0; j < jLen; j++)
        {
            tgt[i][j] = converter(GetEnumerableFor3rdDimension(src, i, j, kLen));
        }
    }
    // return it
    return tgt;
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableFor3rdDimension<T>(T[,,] src, int i, int j, int kLen)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < kLen; k++)
        yield return src[i, j, k];
}
```