# Random 2-D array with LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

How I can create and display random integer 2-D array with LINQ?
Help me please!
I create random 2-D array, but not with LINQ.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int[,] matrix = new int[rows, columns];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        matrix[i, j] = rnd.Next(-100,100);
Console.WriteLine("Array:");
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        Console.Write("{0}\t", matrix[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: LINQ  will most likely result in  less performant and less readable code. It doesn't play   well with multi-dimensional arrays in general.

Comment: As nice of a technology as LINQ is, sometimes its not needed and other times, its not only not needed, but it would overly complicate your code, rather than simplify it. This is an example of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linq to create a 10x10 array:

```
   var r = new Random();
   var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => 
                   Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(y => r.Next()).ToArray())
               .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think it returns jagged array but not 2D array

Comment: Many people had searched for a linq way to convert jagged array to 2d array but none was found. Usually they did it by for loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774901/how-to-convert-list-of-arrays-into-a-2d-array

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to over-complicate this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rows = 10;
        int columns = 10;
        int[,] matrix = new int[rows, columns];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(row => Enumerable.Range(0, columns)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(column => 
                    {
                        matrix[row, column] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
                        Console.Write(column == columns ? Environment.NewLine + matrix[row, column].ToString() + "\t" : matrix[row, column].ToString() + "\t");
                    }));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```