# C# Interop write array of arrays to worksheet

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, interop

I'm trying to write a 2d array to worksheet and I'm getting the following error:

> Specified array was not of the expected type.

This is my code:

```
            string[][] allEvars = new string[evars.Count][];

            for (var i = 0; i < evars.Count; i++) {
                var evarsList = new List<string>();
                evarsList.Add(evars[i].id.Value);
                evarsList.Add(evars[i].name.Value);
                if (evars[i].enabled != null)
                    evarsList.Add(evars[i].enabled.Value.ToString());
                else
                    evarsList.Add("");
                if (evars[i].description != null)
                    evarsList.Add(evars[i].description.Value);
                else
                    evarsList.Add("");
                string[] evarsArray = evarsList.ToArray();
                //var range = (Excel.Range)wsEvars.Range[wsEvars.Cells[i + 5, 2], wsEvars.Cells[i + 5, evarsArray.Length]];
                //range.Value = evarsArray;
                allEvars[i] = evarsList.ToArray();
            }
            var range = (Excel.Range)wsEvars.Range[wsEvars.Cells[5, 2], wsEvars.Cells[allEvars.Length, 3]];
            range.Value2 = allEvars; // This is the line with the exception
```

The 2 commented lines from my code add the array to the worksheet one by one and I'm trying to add them all at once to save some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast array of arrays to 2d array. Use Jon Skeet method from this
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775057/7099599)

```
static T[,] CreateRectangularArray<T>(T[][] arrays)
    {
        // TODO: Validation and special-casing for arrays.Count == 0
        int minorLength = arrays[0].Length;
        T[,] ret = new T[arrays.Length, minorLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
        {
            var array = arrays[i];
            if (array.Length != minorLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException
                    ("All arrays must be the same length");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < minorLength; j++)
            {
                ret[i, j] = array[j];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

In your code:

```
        string[][] allEvars = new string[evars.Count][];

        for (var i = 0; i < evars.Count; i++) {
            var evarsList = new List<string>();
            evarsList.Add(evars[i].id.Value);
            evarsList.Add(evars[i].name.Value);
            if (evars[i].enabled != null)
                evarsList.Add(evars[i].enabled.Value.ToString());
            else
                evarsList.Add("");
            if (evars[i].description != null)
                evarsList.Add(evars[i].description.Value);
            else
                evarsList.Add("");
            string[] evarsArray = evarsList.ToArray();
            //var range = (Excel.Range)wsEvars.Range[wsEvars.Cells[i + 5, 2], wsEvars.Cells[i + 5, evarsArray.Length]];
            //range.Value = evarsArray;
            allEvars[i] = evarsList.ToArray();
        }
        var range = (Excel.Range)wsEvars.Range[wsEvars.Cells[5, 2], wsEvars.Cells[allEvars.Length, 3]];
        string[,] newallEvars = CreateRectangularArray<string>(allEvars); //added row
        range.Value2 = newallEvars; // changed row
```