# Convert List<int[]> to int[,]

Tags: c#

How to convert `List<int[]>` to `int[,]`  where all arrays in the list are `int[2]`?

I'm trying:

```
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
list.Add(new int[2] { 3, 4 });
int[,] arr = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of arrays into a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774901/how-to-convert-list-of-arrays-into-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't convert List to int[,] via `LINQ`.

You need to create new array `[N, 2]` and fill in a loop:

```
var arr = new int[list.Count, 2];

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    arr[i, 0] = list[i][0];
    arr[i, 1] = list[i][1];
}
```