# How to split a string in to a 2D array row or column?

Tags: c#, 2d

I have a string which has many line and space.

For example:

```
string lines = "my name is omar\nliving in whateverf\ng i j";
```

I need to split it into a 2D array in which every word is in an index and each row represents a line.

Which means the 2D array should be more like this:

```
my      name  is omar
living  in    whatever
g       i     j
```

Is it possible?

I have tried splitting it first to lines and then spiting it to words, but I need id in a 2d array

```
string [] l = lines.split('\n');

for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
{
     string [] oneLine= l[i].split(' ');
     //and put the rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: i edited it, hope i made my point more clear :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can have an array or arrays (`string[][]`):

```
 var results = z.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray()).Select(a => a.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```

If you still want to convert it to 2D array (`string[,]`) you can do it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774901/how-to-convert-list-of-arrays-into-a-multidimensional-array).

Answer (score 0):

```
   l=string.split('\n')
   for i in range(0,len(l)):
        l[i]=l[i].split(" ")
    print(l)
```

Split the string on basis of \n and then do again on each basis of word

Comment: i know this way , i need a way to save the whole in put string in a 2D array which has a word in an index, is it possible?

Comment: l is a 2-d array, where you can access a word l[0][1] would give you a certain word