# IList<IList<string>> to 2D String Array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of list strings.  And I want to convert it to 2D string.

I tried the following the code

```
IList<IList<string>> string2DList;
string[,] string2D = string2DList.ToArray();
```

but the above code gives an error on the second line that string2DList.ToArray() is the array of List.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted and closed.  The reference duplicate [How to convert list of arrays into a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774901/how-to-convert-list-of-arrays-into-a-multidimensional-array) deals with List of 1D array, but my question is about list-of-string-list.

Comment: I am not sure. But either way, a [mcve] will help you get an answer faster.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

string[][] string2D = string2DList.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();

Comment: I believe it was downvoted because it creates a nested array instead of a multidimensional array.

Comment: But if we understand the difference between [,] and [][]. string[,] is a rectangular array, while string[][] is known as a "jagged array". In this example its not possible to convert to rectangular array as we can never assure that each list has same length of child strings.

Comment: Hence why we need a [mcve] @Bharat.