# How to search in 2D array by LINQ ?[version2]

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array

I have an **2D** array like this:

```
string[,] ClassNames =
{
  {"A","Red"},
  {"B","Blue"},
  {"C","Pink"},
  {"D","Green"},
  {"X","Black"},
};
```

i search **ClassName** in **1nd** column by **for** statement and return **ColorName** in **2nd** column like this:

```
string className = "A";
string color = "Black";
for (int i = 0; i <= ClassNames.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
   if (ClassNames[i, 0] == className)
   {
      color = ClassNames[i, 1];
      Response.Write(color);
      break;
   }
}
```

i want use **LINQ** instead of **for** statement to get the **color** by **className**.
how to convert above for statement to LINQ.

Comment: Your 2D array looks like it should be a dictionary instead?

Comment: 2D array is in fact a `c` stuff, in c# we should use other collection structure/classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do use the [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method to generate a sequence of integers, and then use Linq to query over that.

Something like this would work:

```
string color = Enumerable
    .Range(0, ClassNames.GetLength(0))
    .Where(i => ClassNames[i, 0] == className)
    .Select(i => ClassNames[i, 1])
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Black";
```

Or in query syntax:

```
string color = 
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, ClassNames.GetLength(0))
     where ClassNames[i, 0] == className
     select ClassNames[i, 1])
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Black";
```

Or perhaps convert the array to a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) first:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ClassNamesDict = Enumerable
    .Range(0, ClassNames.GetLength(0))
    .ToDictionary(i => ClassNames[i, 0], i => ClassNames[i, 1]);
```

And then you can query it much more easily:

```
color = ClassNamesDict.ContainsKey(className) 
      ? ClassNamesDict[className] 
      : "Black";
```

Generating the dictionary first and then querying it will be far more efficient if you have to do a lot of queries like this.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi That's the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It basically means 'if the value to the left is null, use the value to the right instead'. Note that this only works for reference or nullable types. If your actual array is a `int[,]`, you'll have to cast the result to a `(int?)` in the select clause to get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
color = ClassNames.Cast<string>()
                  .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2, (k,x) => x.Select(y => y.x))
                  .Where(g => g.First() == className)
                  .Select(x => x.Last()).First();
```

But to be honest, **I would never use LINQ to do that**. It's less efficient, less readable and worse to maintain. You should consider using your existing `for` loops or change your data structure, to be `List<CustomClass>` or `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `string[,]`.

Comment: You'll get that error when there is no element matching. I've tested it with your sample input and returned `"Red"`.