# Return a single row of an array with ease

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I know I can index a rectangular array with for and `foreach loops` but I feel like I'm missing some syntax knowledge on how to return one specific whole row of an array.

For example if my [3,6] array was like this

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5 6

And I want to just print that middle row to the console, is there an easier way to achieve this than using:

```
int[,] rectArray = new int[3, 6]
{
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
};

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", 
    rectArray[0, 0], 
    rectArray[0, 1], 
    rectArray[0, 2], 
    rectArray[0, 3], 
    rectArray[0, 4], 
    rectArray[0, 5]);
```

I was hoping there might be something I could do like:

```
Console.Writeline(rectArray[0,]);
```

but that does not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: No there is no such way (`rectArray[0,]`) as you mentioned in the question but you can make use of linq for ease.

Comment: No. C# has no syntax to directly do what you're asking. If you want help with a specific implementation of such behavior, please post a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to take input from a user to return an index line would you agree a servicable way to go about it would be say:

if (string indexSearch == "k") then...

'code'
 for (int k = 0; k < rectArray.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(rectArray[1, k] + " ");
            }
'code'

Comment: You could use linq as they do in this question, but it is not that straight forward. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144017/how-to-use-linq-with-a-2-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

To print the Middle row:

```
int middleRow = matrix.GetLength(0)/2;//To get the middle row index
rectArray[middleRow].ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x + " "));
```