# Lambda expression to return a string from a 2D string array based on a test string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array, lambda

I have the following code. I would like to replace the `for` loop to a lambda or LINQ expression to return my string.

```
string[,] testval = new string[3,2]

testval[0, 0] = "0"
testval[0, 1] = "string A"
testval[1, 0] = "5"
testval[1, 1] = "string B"
testval[2, 0] = "13"
testval[2, 1] = "string C"

string teststring = "13"

for (int i=0; i<=testval.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
{
    if (testval[i,0] == teststring) { return testval[i,1]; }
}
return null;
```

I am new to lambda and LINQ expressions. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Rather than using a 2D array and lambda expression, I'd suggest using a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

Comment: Do you mean "lambda" or do you mean "LINQ"?  'Cause I'm not sure what a lambda would get you here, but a LINQ expression might be an alternate way of doing the work while eliminating the explicit loop.

Comment: @davidbak Thanks. Both would work, yes. I just would like to have it simpler than a for loop.

Comment: As long as the keys are unique, a dictionary would be better suited for this.   Then you could do `if (testval.ContainsKey(teststring)) return testval[teststring];`

Comment: Is there maybe a direct command where you don't need to do a loop cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range()` to generate the sequence of integers you want to iterate over, and then build a Linq query over that:

```
var result = Enumerable.
                .Range(0, testval.GetUpperBound(0)+1)
                .Where(i => testval[i,0] == teststring)
                .Select(i => testval[i,1])
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

For using query syntax, or other approaches, look at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673822/how-to-search-in-2d-array-by-linq-version2).

Comment: Great, thank you. So basically you anyway need to loop through them. I wondered if there is another way of doing it without looping.