# C# Pull items from array based on string

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Not sure if this is the best way to do this but I've created a 2D array from values in an excel file that i want to use as variables within my application that control where to look for things like file paths and files.

[image: my data]

The array is built and all data from the file is contained within it:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= bindingSourceConfig.Count - 1; i++) // for each row in the binding source data
   {
       for (int j = 0; j <= 2 - 1; j++) // for each column, only need one and 2
       {
       System_Var_Array[i, j] = (bindingSourceConfig.DataSource as DataTable).Rows[i][j].ToString();
       }
   }
```

Now i want to be able to look in the array for my variable say "Project_Directory" and have it return "C:\Users\User\Dropbox\default\master\support"

Is this even possible?

EDIT 1:
Purpose of doing it this way is to make an easily customizable/configurable multi project environment where by anyone can simply edit the paths in the excel file and import that file into the application.

I can not in my incompetence see a way of setting these 'variables' at a class level without first extracting the 'variable' and the 'value' from the excel data.

Is there a simple way of looking up the 'variable' in bindingSource?

EDIT 2:

[debugger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fQ0n.png)

Comment: Possible, yes, just loop through the array, though you probably want to use Dictionary instead.

Comment: Why do you need `System_Var_Array` with such a for loop since you can optionally work directly on `Rows` or perhaps `Rows.Cast<>().Select(...).ToList()` or `ToArray`? What is your use and purpose? Otherwise to search in the data you can use Linq `Where` and perhaps `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search in 2D array by LINQ ?\[version2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673822/how-to-search-in-2d-array-by-linq-version2)

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. .NET has long supported storing and loading application settings from XML and JSON. Use a native solution, don't write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = "Project_Directory";
string value = null;
for (int i = 0; i<System_Var_Array.GetLength(0); i++) {
   if (System_Var_Array[i,0]==name) {
      value = System_Var_Array[i,1];
      break;
   }
}
```

After the loop stop, `value` will contain the data you need, assuming it exists (otherwise it will be null. A far simpler approach will be using `Dictionary<string,string>`, if you generate it with

```
var systemVars = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var dt = bindingSourceConfig.DataSource as DataTable;
for (int i = 0; i < bindingSourceConfig.Count; i++) // for each row in the binding source data
   {
       systemVars[dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
   }
```

then to get the value for "Project_Directory", simply call

```
var value = systemVars["Project_Directory"];
```

Comment: The dictionary does seem a simpler approach and looks like it will work however i get an error "the given key was not present in the dictionary"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0#examples

Comment: crashes here not when retrieving data systemVars[dt.Rows[i][0]] = systemVars[dt.Rows[i][1]];

Comment: Tried .ToString() and dont doubt that its working on your end.  Infact it returns the value [i][1] but still crashes and throws the key not found error. Will edit my question to show screenshot of debugger

Comment: the culprit was that line.  this is what worked for me: systemVars.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());

Answer (score -1):

You should use an appsettings file for this instead, it's the dotnet standard solution for this sort of thing.  Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration.