# Delete elements from 2d array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

How ca I delete an entire row from an 2d array? I want to keep deleting 1 row from the array shipPosition,untill it doesn`t have any elements.

```
shipPosition -= shipPosition[0,0]
```

and

```
shipPosition -= shipPosition[0,1]
```

E.g.

```
int[,] shipPosition = new int[3, 2];

shipPosition[0, 0] = 2;
shipPosition[0, 1] = 3;
shipPosition[1, 0] = 4;
shipPosition[1, 1] = 5;
shipPosition[2, 0] = 6;
shipPosition[2, 1] = 7;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through 2 dimensional array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184306/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete rows and columns from 2D array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303030/how-can-i-delete-rows-and-columns-from-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303030/how-can-i-delete-rows-and-columns-from-2d-array-in-c

Answer (score 1):

In C# arrays (of whatever dimension) are of fixed size. You can change the content of an element, but you can't add or remove elements (and therefor rows).

You'll need to write (or find from a third party) a class that manages this for you (much like `List<T>` effectively allows changing the number of elements in a 1D array).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change collection's *type*: `List<int[]>` (*list* of *array*s) instead of *2d array*:

```
  List<int[]> shipPosition = new List<int[]>() {
    new int[] {2, 3}, // 1st line 
    new int[] {4, 5}, // 2nd line 
    new int[] {6, 7}, // ...  
  };
```

Now, if you want to remove enrire row (say the top one, `{2, 3}`), just do it

```
 shipPosition.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach with `for` loop

```
public static int[,] DeleteRow(int rowDeleteIndex, int[,] sourceArray)
{
    int rows = sourceArray.GetLength(0);
    int cols = sourceArray.GetLength(1);
    int[,] result = new int[rows - 1, cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (i != rowDeleteIndex)
            {
                result[i >= rowDeleteIndex ? i - 1 : i, j] = sourceArray[i, j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

so you can

```
int[,] shipPosition = new int[3, 2] { { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 } };
int[,] result = DeleteRow(1, shipPosition);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsrjoZ